# Dual Container View Animation iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-animation

So I've got a ViewController, which has two Container Views.  The top one is the main content.  The bottom one is a banner that will hide/show on certain events.

The bottom one is positioned such that it is under the tab bar until the event occurs.

When the event occurs, the frame of the main view is shrank and the frame of the banner is repositioned, such that it appears to 'slide' into the view and become available.

The problem I'm having is, unless I resize the main view in the storyboard (which is not what I want), any resizing I do in code DOES reveal the banner, but the banner does not respond to touches.  (Resizing in storyboard, it does respond.)  It seems that there's some other view in front of it that's intercepting the touches, but what, and how do I fix it?

The main view controller:

```
func hideBanner() {
    bannerViewController?.toggleBannerDisplay(show: false)
    contentTableViewController?.toggleBannerDisplay(show: false)
}
func showBanner() {
    bannerViewController?.toggleBannerDisplay(show: true)
    contentTableViewController?.toggleBannerDisplay(show: true)
}
```

The content table view controller:

```
func toggleBannerDisplay(show: Bool) {
    let tableView = self.view as! UITableView

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        if self.cancelApplyShowing == false && show == true {
            let frame = tableView.frame
            let newFrame = CGRect(x:frame.origin.x , y: frame.origin.y, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height - 48)
            tableView.contentSize = newFrame.size
            tableView.frame = newFrame
            self.cancelApplyShowing = true
        } else if self.cancelApplyShowing == true && show == false {
            let frame = tableView.frame
            let newFrame = CGRect(x:frame.origin.x , y: frame.origin.y, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height + 48)
            tableView.contentSize = newFrame.size
            tableView.frame = newFrame
            self.cancelApplyShowing = false
        }
    })
}
```

The banner:

```
func toggleBannerDisplay(show: Bool) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        if self.cancelApplyShowing == false && show == true {
            let frame = self.view.frame
            let newFrame = CGRect(x: frame.origin.x, y: frame.origin.y - 48, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height)
            self.view.frame = newFrame
            self.cancelApplyShowing = true
        } else if self.cancelApplyShowing == true && show == false {
            self.view.frame.origin.y += 48
            self.cancelApplyShowing = false
        }
    })
}
```

For some reason, if I resize that main view, the hidden view becomes responsive (after animations of course).

[image: Storyboard Screenshot]

Vimeo video: https://vimeo.com/246496442

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to animate the embedded view controller's views, which did bring everything up and into place, but the container view was still sitting invisibly over the top.

I **animated the container views** and everything works fine now.