# iOS Animated Views Disappear after Autorotation

Tags: ios, animation

Please see: [Dual Container View Animation iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47719533/dual-container-view-animation-ios) for a description of my views and details on what I'm trying to do.

Basically, it's two container views that are animating.  In the above described thread, I'm animating the frames, which I've discovered has problems.

I've now started animating the constraint and the frame, but

1) I'm not sure if what I'm doing is right.
2) When I rotate the device and then rotate it back, the animated views move back.

**How can I prevent my animated views from disappearing when the autorotation is activated?  Thanks in advance.**

My hide/show code:

```
 func hideBanner() {
    guard isBannerShowing == true else { return }

    self.isBannerShowing = false
    let adjustment = self.cancelApplyView.frame.size.height

    let tableViewFrame = tableContainerView.frame
    let newTableViewFrame = CGRect(x: tableViewFrame.origin.x, y: tableViewFrame.origin.y, width: tableViewFrame.size.width, height: tableViewFrame.height + adjustment)
    let cancelApplyFrame = cancelApplyView.frame
    let newCancelApplyFrame = CGRect(x: cancelApplyFrame.origin.x, y: cancelApplyFrame.origin.y + adjustment, width: cancelApplyFrame.size.width, height: cancelApplyFrame.height)

    self.view.updateConstraints()
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.tableContainerBottomConstraint.constant = 0
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.tableContainerView.frame = newTableViewFrame
        self.cancelApplyView.frame = newCancelApplyFrame
    })
}
func showBanner() {
    guard isBannerShowing == false else { return }

    self.isBannerShowing = true
    let adjustment = self.cancelApplyView.frame.size.height

    let newConstraintVal = cancelApplyView.frame.size.height

    let tableViewFrame = tableContainerView.frame
    let newTableViewFrame = CGRect(x: tableViewFrame.origin.x, y: tableViewFrame.origin.y, width: tableViewFrame.size.width, height: tableViewFrame.height - adjustment)
    let cancelApplyFrame = cancelApplyView.frame
    let newCancelApplyFrame = CGRect(x: cancelApplyFrame.origin.x, y: cancelApplyFrame.origin.y - adjustment, width: cancelApplyFrame.size.width, height: cancelApplyFrame.height)

    self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.cancelApplyView)
    self.view.updateConstraints()

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.tableContainerBottomConstraint.constant = newConstraintVal
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.tableContainerView.frame = newTableViewFrame
        self.cancelApplyView.frame = newCancelApplyFrame
    })

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't have to do both auto/frame layout change

Hook banner top constraint to the table and make the banner's bottom = view.bottom + bannerHeight

Hide

```
    self.bannerTopConstraint.constant = -1* bannerHeight
    self.cancelApplyViewTopConstraint.constant = 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {        
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()         
    })
```

Show

```
    self.bannerTopConstraint.constant = 0
    self.cancelApplyViewTopConstraint.constant = -1 * adjustment 
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {        
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()         
    })
```

Comment: Thank you.  This does fix the problem with Autorotation, but now the view does not animate.  It only 'pops', or suddenly appears, without the animation.

Comment: Maybe I've got something set incorrectly.  I'm confused a little bit.  I have a TableView in a container view and a banner in a container view.  The one that should resize up is "tableContainerView", the one that should slide into view is "cancelApplyView".

Comment: only change the owner of the bottom constraint

Comment: Got it!  I had the constant assignments inside the animation block and the layoutIfNeeded outside.  Thanks!!

Comment: Done bro ,,,,,,,,